# windows phone 8 doesnt support angularjs routing

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have created an app using phonegap for iphone, android and windows.

iphone and android works fine but in windows phone I am able to see only home page there is something issue with angularjs routing when I touch on any link it display page not found. Or ng-href is not redirecting to respective page.

Please help its the crical and wierd issue for me.

Thanks, 
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide more details and some code snippet of your app, otherwise it'll be difficult to answer your question.

I encountered similar issue before, and these are the things that I did to solve it:

1. Specify namespace in your html and put the ng-app in the html tag

   `<html  xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="app" id="ng-app">`
2. Manually run your angular on device ready event

   `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
              angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
   }, false);`
3. Make sure you have included ngRoute, in your index.html

   `<script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>`

   and in your angular

   `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);`
4. Watch out for jQuery if you are using any, sometimes it is the jQuery that is causing the problem/ incompatible.
5. There is also XHR problem: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4288#issuecomment-26429558, so just make sure you are using the latest Phonegap.

Just some of the general answer that I could give, hope it solve your issue.